# How to create a calculated column to pull the year of Date column 1, and if blank, pull year from Date column 2, if that's also blank then put Hold

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to create a calculated column that looks at the Date1 column and pulls only the year into the new column. If the Date1 column is blank, then bring in the Date2 column. If Date2 column is blank, then display "Review".

If Date1 or Date2 is in 1st quarter (Jan-Mar), then I need the year to display the previous year. (example 2/15/2024 should display 2023 in the calculated column).

I have started with this formula

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date1]),"Review",TEXT([Date1],"yyyy"))
```

How can I modify this to include the additional requirements of looking at Date2 column and the 1st quarter?

Desired output

| Date1 | Date2 | Year (calculated column) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5/13/2024 |  | 2024 |
| 2/14/2024 |  | 2023 |
|  | 7/11/2024 | 2024 |
|  |  | Review |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using formula like below for your SharePoint calculated column (Year):

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date1]),IF(ISBLANK([Date2]),"Review",IF(OR(MONTH([Date2])=1,MONTH([Date2])=2,MONTH([Date2])=3),YEAR([Date2])-1,YEAR([Date2]))),IF(OR(MONTH([Date1])=1,MONTH([Date1])=2,MONTH([Date1])=3),YEAR([Date1])-1,YEAR([Date1])))
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Notes**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.

---

**Update from comments**:

Try using calculated column formula like below to remove commas from calculated column results:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date1]),IF(ISBLANK([Date2]),"Review",IF(OR(MONTH([Date2])=1,MONTH([Date2])=2,MONTH([Date2])=3),TEXT(YEAR([Date2])-1,"####"),TEXT(YEAR([Date2]),"####"))),IF(OR(MONTH([Date1])=1,MONTH([Date1])=2,MONTH([Date1])=3),TEXT(YEAR([Date1])-1,"####"),TEXT(YEAR([Date1]),"####")))
```

Comment: Thanks so much Ganesh! The calculations are working as expected! The only problem is I have commas in my Calculated Year column. Field is Single line of Text, not sure why the comma is being added. Any additional tips?

Comment: @ganesh-sanap-mvp I was able to revise the formatting for most of the calculations to remove the commas in the year but for the items that fall in Q1 and are taking the previous year, the commas are still present. Any advice?

Comment: Hi @kendallyn, can you show us the updated/current formula you are using which removes comma from some of the years?

Comment: Try using the formula given in updated answer above.

Comment: Hi @ganesh sanap - MVP, this is the updated formula I have: =IF(ISBLANK([Date1]),IF(ISBLANK([Date2]),"Review",IF(OR(MONTH([Date2])=1,MONTH([Date2])=2,MONTH([Date2])=3),TEXT([Date2],"yyyy")-1,TEXT([Date2],"yyyy"))),IF(OR(MONTH([Date1])=1,MONTH([Date1])=2,MONTH([Date1])=3),TEXT([Date1],"yyyy")-1,TEXT([Date1],"yyyy"))) . I will try the updated formula you provided and let you know the results.

Comment: The updated formula you provided solved my problem!! Thanks again for your time and expertise, it is much appreciated!